# Why would there be a piece of retzuah in the compartment of the tefillin shel yad?

Tags: tefilin

Recently, I came across an old pair of [*tefillin peshutim*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67914/define-the-terms-used-for-types-or-grades-of-tefillin) of mine. They became un-fit for use years ago, and I have since replaced them with a sturdier pair, B''H. They aren't vintage, but they have seen better days for sure (*peshutim* don't hold up well in day-to-day use).

Understanding that they were a cheap pair, I was curious as to what the parchments looked like inside. I'd heard "horror stories" about cheap *tefillin*, and although I don't have the know-how to declare *tefillin* or *mezuzos* useable or not, I wasn't impressed with what I saw.

Anyway, when I opened up the *tefillin shel yad* and removed the parchment, something else fell out of the box. Upon inspection, I found that it was a small piece of cut *retzuah* (leather strap) that was stuffed in the compartment along with the parchment. I must say this was very unexpected.

I have never heard of any custom of putting a piece of *retzuah* in with the parchment.  Why would there be a piece of *retzuah* in the compartment of the *tefillin shel yad* along with the parchment?

Comment: Simple question. Are you sure this wasn't just carelessness?

Comment: I think it's just filler to hold the parchment in place (like packing peanuts)

Comment: Is the bayit allowed to have anything extra like this? (BTW, nice avatar. Is it you?)

Comment: @DoubleAA That sounds very plausible, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is filler material to prevent the parchment from turning or slipping down and it is not a good idea.

[R Yerachmiel Askotzky](http://www.stam.net/about_me.aspx) in his book [Tefillin and Mezuzos](http://a.co/gZZ3cz8) writes (p. 89)

> According to some *poskim*, loose *klaf* or a piece of *retzuah* should
> preferably not be placed between a *parashah* [*klaf*] and the wall of the
> *bayit* to prevent it from turning or slipping down, as it will separate
> between the *parashah* and the majority of a wall or *shin*.
>
> Instead, the
> *matlit* (the piece of parchment or animal skin that serves inside the tefillin boxes as a protective covering over the *parshiot* of the *tefillin*) should be made very long so that the excess can be used
> to make an accordion that will hold it it place.
>
> Note: one cannot cut
> pieces from a used *retzuah* to hold the *parashiot* in place within the
> batim.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is an old question, but it caught my eye and I have a different possible explanation. Are you sure that the piece of retzuah was actuality in the compartment with the klaf? The reason I ask is that the sofer I use puts a small piece of retzuah in the Ma'abarta (the area that the retzuah is passed through). He does this to hold the retzuah in place so the knot stays against the bayis (many will tie a piece of sinew through the Ma'abarta and around the knot to achieve the same goal). It's possible that in your case this is where the piece fell from when you opened it, as opposed to from inside the bayis itself.

Comment: No, the retzu'ah was mamish in the bayis

Comment: Just a thought. Not quite sure why it's deserving of a down vote though.